# How do I use Debug.Writeline in a razor file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to use Debug.Writeline in a razor web page and I keep getting invalid arguments messages.

@System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("asdf");

returns

CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Debug.WriteLine` does not return a value so it can't be written out using `@`. Try:

```
@{System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("asdf");}
```